# Gnome is being incredibly unstable and applications are frequently crashing

Tags: 14.04, gnome, crash

I don't know how this happened, after I updated my software everything on Gnome started breaking. This is what I have noticed so far:

- The terminal crashes when I click on the menu items
- The `Screenshot` application crashes when I try to save a screenshot
- The `Clocks` application crashes when I try to add a new clock

The terminal also looks weird, it used to be white. This must be due to missing files or something: (I couldn't crop it because `Shotwell Viewer` kept crashing

[image]

I assume that I must be missing files or something, but when I do `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` nothing happens.

I'm running 3.12.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

It's only getting worse, and I believe it occured after trying to upgrade to Gnome 3.14. How can I fix this?

Comment: You could try `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: @Zacharee1 nothing installed, updated or anything

Comment: maybe reinstall the GNOME desktop?

Comment: @Zacharee1 How can I do that without messing anything up or loosing my files? I've already installed Ubuntu twice over the past day due to things messing up...

Comment: You won't lose your files or anything. Just `sudo apt-get install --reinstall whatever-the-package-name-for-gnome-desktop-is`. And then `sudo dpkg-reconfigure same-package-name`.reboot

Comment: I don't know what the package name is @Zacharee1

Comment: I think it's `gnome-desktop-environment`

Comment: @Zacharee1 didn't work

Comment: Hmm. Maybe install KDE or Unity, go into that, purge GNOME and then reinstall GNOME.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that, and it's probably going to be too much to fit in a comment. Can you please make an answer?

Comment: Sure I can. Give me a few

Answer (score 0):

OK. This is really a workaround, but it's the only way I can think of short of reinstalling completely. Since reconfiguring and reinstalling GNOME didn't work, I have to go with this.

First, you need to install another desktop interface, such as KDE or Unity. I recommend Unity, since it shares a lot of packages with GNOME, and will be a smaller download.

1. To install Unity, run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^`.
2. Log out and look for a gear icon or GNOME themed icon, usually near the login Window. Click this and choose the `Unity` option and log back in. You should now be in Unity.
3. Open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install lightdm` and then `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. Choose `lightdm` in the window that hopefully comes up. If it doesn't, comment and I'll help.
4. Run `sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-shell`. Reboot.
5. After the reboot (your login screen *will* be different), run `sudo apt-get install gnome-desktop-environment` and then `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` to select `gdm`.
6. Reboot and hopefully you'll be back at the original login screen.
7. Click the icon to switch the desktop environment and choose GNOME before logging back in.

Hopefully everything will be fixed. If you want to remove Unity, just run `sudo apt-get remove unity`.

**If you can't find the icon on the login screen or if the reconfigure commands don't work, tell me and I'll see if I can help.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27302/discussion-on-answer-by-zacharee1-gnome-is-being-incredibly-unstable-and-applica).

Comment: @Mitch It already _was_ in the chat.